# Django can't get admin static files in Apache server

Tags: django

Django can't get admin static files in Apache server. What can I do?.................................... ......................................................................... ..................

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin mazlum.agar@gmail.com
ServerName modeller.com
ServerAlias www.modeller.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/modeller

Alias /static/ /var/www/modeller/statik_dosyalar/
Alias /static/admin/ /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static       .

<Directory "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/">
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>


WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/www/modeller/modeller/wsgi.py"


<Directory /var/www/modeller>
Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/modeller/statik_dosyalar>
Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory /var/www/modeller/static>
Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/modeller/media>
Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 Alias /static/admin/ /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static
```

to

```
Alias /static/admin/ "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media"
```

And in settings:

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

Comment: Thank you for feedback. But it doesn't wok.

Comment: Hope you checked in the path right. I still use 2.6 in most places. From you settings i see its 2.7. Just wanted to make sure